# Netty TCP push/streaming server

Tags: java, tcp, netty

Is it possible to implement request for stream style client server interactions at the tcp level in netty? The protocol would essentially follow:

t0: tcp handshake

t1: client requests topic X

t2-tn: server sends latest enqueued update on topic X

I've seen a netty websockets example, but is it possible, and are there examples, to do this in netty at the tcp level?

Edit: I'm really not asking if this is the correct way to implement the feature, or if there is another solution involving installation of third party software, even if it would be the "right" thing to do. I am asking if this is possible to do using netty.

I would be very interested to hear from any users of netty's SCTP features, any metrics appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by transport level? It sounds like you need something like a message queue where it should be easily implemented.

Comment: transport level as in one level below application level. Without organisational constraints I would just use rabbit, yes.

Comment: Transport layer is not a good layer to implement this as Java does not really support a way to let you implement your own transport layer unless you use JNI for that.

Comment: I'm pretty familiar with Netty but transport is quite an overloaded term here. In Netty documentation, it pretty much refers to transport layer such as tcp, udp, sctp, etc. with some specification calling implementation such as NIO, OIO, local etc. I believe what you want to implement should be layered on top of that.

Comment: To be clear, what's being asked is how to stream a bunch of byte arrays through a TCP socket using netty. The reason I ask to do this at the transport level is that I don't want to use an application level protocol, i.e. websockets or HTTP long polling. Thanks.

Comment: Then what you want is channel handler that handles your custom application level protocol. What you need is to design your own protocol and handle the topic subscription and then create a ChannelGroup for each topic properly. When there is a message coming in, you just need to look up for a relevant ChannelGroup and then broadcast the information http://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/channel/group/ChannelGroup.html

Comment: OK so when my server generates topical updates to send to clients if there are any listeners on those topics, it looks up the ChannelGroup for the topic and calls ChannelGroup.write? I guess when the client requests a topic, the channel on which the request was made should be added to a new or existing ChannelGroup indexed by the topic? The protocol is already designed, just trying to plug into netty's programming model... Thanks.

Comment: That's correct. You just need to have ConcurrentMap<Topic, ChannelGroup> kept somewhere so that you can look it up inside ChannelHandler.

Comment: OK thanks. So at this level I'll be doing so much myself I don't get much advantage over using plain sockets really.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nat answered my question - adding and removing the incoming channel from the sender's channelgroup in channelActive and channelInactive allows messages of arbitrary structure to be pushed to subscribing clients.